# How to filter (hide) Pre-flight requests on my Dev Tools Network

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, preflight

Normally both calls are shown, the pre-flight and the actual request. This is sometimes annoying. Is there a way to hide the pre-flights requests ?

Or is there a plugin to filter certain requests based on headers ?

Answer (score 462, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to filter on `-method:OPTIONS`.

[image]

Explanation: all pre-flight requests are via the HTTP OPTIONS method (opposed to POST or GET). This filter says "not method OPTIONS".

Note the leading hyphen because if you forget it, you'll *only* show pre-flight requests.

Comment: This is number 8 on my biggest frustrations in development  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. Is there any way to add other filters to that field? For example
`searchTerm -method:OPTIONS` (not working for me).

Comment: You can add domain and other filters with a comma, as in: "-method:OPTIONS, domain:*.google.com". See full options here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading#filter_requests

Comment: The chrome team needs to add a checkbox to hide them. This is important feature to prevent noise.

Comment: @Touch I agree! Is there somewhere to vote for this?

Comment: Not only this, the Chrome team should just let us define a custom filter which actually gets remembered across sessions, tabs, etc. That way we can block socket requests to things like BrowserSync, Intercom and Stripe as well, which just create noise at the moment.

Comment: There is a feature request to preserve filters after reopening DevTools, please see [this link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796893). Star it if you're tired of typing `-method:OPTIONS` every time you open DevTools.

Comment: It looks like CORS preflight behavior is changing with Chrome's `OOR-CORS` implementation (https://dev.chromium.org/Home/loading/oor-cors). With the latest canary I no longer see any preflight requests in devtools - the only way I can see them for debugging purposes is to use Fiddler or a NetLog dump.

Comment: The chromium feature request to persist filters won't be implemented, see [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=796893#c13) comment by petermueller@chromium.org

Comment: Also works in Firefox's Dev tools

Comment: There used to be an experimental attempt at grouping preflight with the origin request but after a while it disappeared. I wish it'd come back...

Comment: sadly doesn't seem to work https://i.imgur.com/VAZTl69.png

Answer (score 66):

By default, "All" requests will be displayed in the network tab. To see OPTIONS requests, you can select "Other". To see only your web api requests, you can select "XHR" (which won't show OPTIONS request).

[image]

Comment: this is must be the ✅ selected answer ,thanks 

Comment: Does not work on firefox

Comment: @Marius also does not work on Internet Explorer 3

Comment: sadly doesn't seem to work https://i.imgur.com/VAZTl69.png

Comment: Selecting XHR + filtering with `-method:OPTIONS` works on Firefox