# How to check CORS Preflight response status code in js?

Tags: javascript, http, request, xmlhttprequest

Is there any way to get a status code of a CORS Preflight response?
[Preflight response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWd21.png)

I would like to make a condition for status of Preflight request.

The code I have right now:

```
let requestInCheck = new XMLHttpRequest();
requestInCheck.open("GET", "http://google.COM/", true); //CORS
requestInCheck.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
requestInCheck.timeout = TIME_OUT;

requestInCheck.onerror = () => {
  console.log(`There was an error while trying to make the request [STATUS: ${requestInCheck.status}]`);

  serviceAcception = false;
   
  this.setState({ serviceAcception });
}

requestInCheck.onload = () => {
  console.log(`The response code is [STATUS: ${requestInCheck.status}]`);

  if(requestInCheck.status !== 0) 
    serviceAcception = true;
   
  this.setState({ serviceAcception });
} //...send method is below
```

Since the request is unable to be responded correctly, "onerror" is called and respectful message is logged: [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwN7v.png)

Is there a way I can get preflight status code into some variable or smth?

Comment: There is no way as a preflight, but you can send an OPTIONS request yourself. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request . However, everything you need [should be visible in your dev tools' network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567580/how-to-filter-hide-pre-flight-requests-on-my-dev-tools-network).

Comment: @JuanMendes Thank you for an answer, I'll look what I can do with it.